# Flutter: change language only updates the current page

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-dependencies

This is what I have when changing the locale:

```
 if (newLang is! String) return;
                  _language = newLang;
                  changeLocale(context, newLang);
                  Locale(newLang, ''); // method 1
                  MyApp.of(context)!.setLocale(Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: newLang)); // method 2
                  Provider.of<TimesAp>(context, listen: false).changeLanguage(newLang); // method 3
                  });
```

As you can see I added 2 extra methods that I was checking, but none of them seem to work so I was thinking the problem could be somewhere else.

```
void setLocale(Locale value) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = value; // method 2
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<TimesAp>(create: (_) => TimesAp()), // method 3
      ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    // locale: getSavedLanguage(context),
    locale: _locale, // method 2
    supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
    localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      localizationDelegate
    ],
```

method 3:

```
class TimesAp extends ChangeNotifier {
  String locale = 'en';

  changeLanguage(String newLang) {
    locale = newLang;
    updateUI();
  }

  updateUI() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I have landing and options page, where I do the language update. For that page everything changes, but when I go back nothing did. It does when I refresh (I save it in the shared preferences).

https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z7ec06l27ed0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/options.dart

Answer (score 0):

2 things missing:

```
 LocalizationProvider(
      state: LocalizationProvider.of(context).state,
      child:  MaterialApp(
```

and `home:` can't return a const